# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST?

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I am getting this Error:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST

while Executing the Following code through Execute Anonymous:

```
public List<id> sitecontractids = new List<id>();
public List<Engineer_Checklist__c> ssnewList = new List<Engineer_Checklist__c>();
public List<SiteContracts__c> scnewlist= new List<SiteContracts__c>();
public List<SiteContracts__c> newsc = new List<SiteContracts__c>();
public List<SiteContracts__c> scList =[SELECT id, name From SiteContracts__c LIMIT 200];

 for(SiteContracts__c scnewid :scList ){
         sitecontractids.add(scnewid.id);
   }
    ssnewList =[Select Id, X6L_Water_Qty__c, X9L_Water_Qty__c, X3L_Water_Mist_Qty__c, X6L_Water_Mist_Qty__c, X9L_Water_Mist_Qty__c,
                           X2L_AFFF_Qty__c, X3L_AFFF_Qty__c, X6L_AFFF_Qty__c, X9L_AFFF_Qty__c, X2KG_CO2_Qty__c, X5KG_CO2_Qty__c,
                           X1_KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c, X2KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c, X4KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c, X6KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c,
                           X9KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c, X3L_Wet_Chem_Qty__c, X6L_Wet_Chem_Qty__c, X1X1_Fire_blan_Qty__c, X12x12_FB_Qty__c,
                           X12x18_FB_Qty__c, XHose_Reel_19_Qty__c, FA_Travel_Time__c, FA_Job_Time__c, ALUnit_Qty__c,
                           FA_Smoke_Detector_Qty__c, FA_Heat_Detector_Qty__c, FA_Break_Glass_Call_Point_Qty__c,
                           FA_Bell_Sounder_Qty__c, FA_Automatic_Door_qty__c, FA_Central_Station_Link_Qty__c,
                           FA_Remote_Indicator_Qty__c, FA_Beacon_Qty__c, FA_Emergency_Light_Qty__c, FA_Keyswitch_Qty__c,
                           FA_Type_of_Panel__c, Age_of_Panel__c
            From Engineer_Checklist__c 
            Where Fire_Extinguisher_Service_complete__c=true AND Site_Contract__c !=NULL AND
                 Site_Contract__c IN :sitecontractids  Order By lastmodifieddate desc LIMIT 200];
 for(Engineer_Checklist__c ssli:ssnewList)
{
newsc.X6L_Water__c=ssli.X6L_Water_Qty__c;
newsc.X9L_Water__c=ssli.X9L_Water_Qty__c;
newsc.X3L_Water_Mist__c=ssli.X3L_Water_Mist_Qty__c;
newsc.X6L_Water_Mist__c=ssli.X6L_Water_Mist_Qty__c;
newsc.X9L_Water_Mist__c=ssli.X9L_Water_Mist_Qty__c;
newsc.X2L_AFFF__c=ssli.X2L_AFFF_Qty__c;
newsc.X3L_AFFF__c=ssli.X3L_AFFF_Qty__c;
newsc.X6L_AFFF__c=ssli.X6L_AFFF_Qty__c;
newsc.X9L_AFFF__c=ssli.X9L_AFFF_Qty__c;
newsc.X2KG_CO2__c=ssli.X2KG_CO2_Qty__c;
newsc.X5KG_CO2__c=ssli.X5KG_CO2_Qty__c;
newsc.X1KG_DRY_POWDER__c=ssli.X1_KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c;
newsc.X2KG_DRY_POWDER__c=ssli.X2KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c;
newsc.X4KG_DRY_POWDER__c=ssli.X4KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c;
newsc.X6KG_DRY_POWDER__c=ssli.X6KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c;
newsc.X9KG_DRY_POWDER__c=ssli.X9KG_Dry_Powder_Qty__c;
newsc.X3L_WET_CHEMICAL__c=ssli.X3L_Wet_Chem_Qty__c;
newsc.X6L_WET_CHEMICAL__c=ssli.X6L_Wet_Chem_Qty__c;
newsc.X1_x_1m_Fire_Blanket__c=ssli.X1X1_Fire_blan_Qty__c;
newsc.X1_2_x_1_2m_Fire_Blanket__c=ssli.X12x12_FB_Qty__c;
newsc.X1_2_x_1_8m_Fire_Blanket__c=ssli.X12x18_FB_Qty__c;
newsc.Hose_Reel_19mm__c=ssli.XHose_Reel_19_Qty__c;
newsc.Al_Unit__c=ssli.ALUnit_Qty__c;
newsc.Smoke_Detector_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Smoke_Detector_Qty__c;
newsc.Heat_Detector_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Heat_Detector_Qty__c;
newsc.Break_Glass_Call_Point_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Break_Glass_Call_Point_Qty__c;
newsc.Bell_Sounder_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Bell_Sounder_Qty__c;
newsc.Automatic_Door_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Automatic_Door_qty__c;
newsc.Central_Station_Link_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Central_Station_Link_Qty__c;
newsc.Remote_Indicator_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Remote_Indicator_Qty__c;
newsc.Beacon_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Beacon_Qty__c;
newsc.Emergency_Light_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Emergency_Light_Qty__c;
newsc.Keyswitch_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Keyswitch_Qty__c;
newsc.Type_of_Panel_DVR__c=ssnewlist.FA_Type_of_Panel__c;
newsc.Age_of_Panel_DVR__c=ssnewlist.Age_of_Panel__c;
newsc.Job_Time__c=ssnewlist.FA_Job_Time__c;
newsc.Travel_Time__c=ssnewlist.FA_Travel_Time__c;
newsc.Time__c='Minutes';
newsc.Job_time_value__c='Hours';

scnewlist.add(newsc);
}
update scnewlist;
```

Can any one suggest me what is wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `newsc` is declared to be a `List<SiteContracts__c>` but you are using it as if it is a `SiteContracts__c`.

One way to fix this is to delete the current `newsc` definition and have your loop like this instead:

```
for(Engineer_Checklist__c ssli : ssnewList)
{
    SiteContracts__c newsc = new SiteContracts__c();
    newsc.X6L_Water__c = ssli.X6L_Water_Qty__c;
    ...
    scnewlist.add(newsc);
}
update scnewlist;
```

Or if you can bear the editing, SObjects support named parameters in their constructors so the code can be written like this:

```
for(Engineer_Checklist__c ssli : ssnewList)
{
    scnewlist.add(new SiteContracts__c(
            X6L_Water__c = ssli.X6L_Water_Qty__c,
            ...
            ));
}
update scnewlist;
```

Comment: I did as u said but same Error.

Comment: @KartiK I now see that further down you also have starting with this line `newsc.Smoke_Detector_Qty__c=ssnewlist.FA_Smoke_Detector_Qty__c;` a number of lines where you are referencing `ssnewlist` - a list - instead of (presumably) `ssli` - a reference to a single object. Change those.

Comment: Now getting this error after editing as u said,-  System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []

Comment: @KartiK Change `update scnewlist;` to `insert scnewlist;`.

Comment: Keith again throughing an Error-System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements

Comment: @KartiK That is usually because the same object reference has been added to the list more than once. I'm going to stop commenting at this point; rather than posting ever problem you run into you would gain more insight by trying to figure it out yourself (with the help of Google).

Answer (score 0):

Change the List- scnewlist to set.

```
public set<SiteContracts__c> scnewlist= new set<SiteContracts__c>();
public set<SiteContracts__c> finalscnewlist= new set<SiteContracts__c>();
```

and use set variable to store the 'newsc'.

```
finalscnewlist.addall(scnewlist);
insert finalscnewlist;
```

Thanks,
Raviteja

Comment: Thanks Raviteja, and Kindly can you tel me How to set variable to store the 'newsc'. ?

Comment: Take two collection types one is Set type and another list type as below,public set<SiteContracts__c> scnewset= new set<SiteContracts__c>();
public List<SiteContracts__c> finalscnewlist= new List<SiteContracts__c>();             for(){       scnewset.add(newsc);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          }  finalscnewlist.addall(scnewlist); insert finalscnewlist;